# How to fix errors in switch operator

Tags: c#, .net

I have a class named config with two string fields named key paramValue and parameterPath.

When I apply the ChooseType method of the class, the method has to return one variable paramValue in different types (Int or bool or String).

I implemented it as follow:

```
class ConfigValue
{
    public string parameterPath;
    private string paramValue;

    public ConfigValue(string ParameterPath="empty",string ParamValue="empty")
    {
        this.parameterPath = ParameterPath;
        this.paramValue = ParameterPath;
    }

    public enum RetType { RetInt=1, RetBool, RetString };



    public  T ChooseType<T>(RetType how)
    {

        {

            switch(how)
             {
                case RetType.RetInt:

                     return int.Parse(string this.paramValue);
                        break;

                case RetType.RetBool:

                    return  Boolean.Parse(string this.paramValue);
                        break;

                case RetType.RetString:

                       return this.paramValue;
                      break;
             }

         }
    }

}
```

But,I get error in switch operator in the next rows:

```
 return int.Parse(string this.paramValue);
```

Error:

> Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement.

```
 return  Boolean.Parse(string this.paramValue);
```

Error:

> Invalid expression term 'string'.

```
 return this.paramValue;
```

Error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'T'.

Any idea why do I get these errors and how can I fix the code?

Comment: "return int.Parse(string this.paramValue)" is not a valid statement.  Should probably be "return int.Parse(this.paramValue)"

Comment: svanryckeghem, in this case i get this Error:Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'T'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public T ChooseType<T>(RetType how)
{
    switch (how)
    {
        case RetType.RetInt:
            return (dynamic)int.Parse(paramValue);
        case RetType.RetBool:
            return (dynamic)Boolean.Parse(paramValue);
        case RetType.RetString:
            return (dynamic)paramValue;
        default:
            throw new ArgumentException("RetType not supported", "how");
    }
}
```

You should not specify parameter type when you are calling some method. Parameter types required only for method declaration. Thus just pass parameter:

```
int.Parse(this.paramValue) // you can use class members without this keyword
int.Parse(paramValue)
```

Also you should add `default` branch for your switch block (you must return something if incorrect parameter value was passed to your method).

Also you don't need to `break` switch branches if you already used `return`.

And for converting some type to generic value you should use `dynamic`, or double conversion via object:

```
return (dynamic)int.Parse(paramValue);
return (T)(object)int.Parse(paramValue);
```

Answer (score 6):

> Any idea why do I get these errors?

The compiler has no idea what `T` will be, and it doesn't know how to implicitly convert from `string`, `bool` or `int` to `T`.

> and how can I fix the code?

You can go through an explicit conversion to `object` and then another to `T`:

```
return (T) (object) int.Parse(string this.paramValue);
```

The requirement to go "via" `object` is a little odd - Eric Lippert has a [blog post going through this in more detail](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2012/07/10/when-is-a-cast-not-a-cast.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are stating that the return type of your function will be T. As T can be of ANY type, you can't explicitely return an int, string or any speciffic type. You may want to try using one return instruction, something like

```
public  T ChooseType<T>() 
{
    return (T)this.paramValue;
}
```

and then, when calling the function, specify T, like this:

```
int a = ChooseType<int>();
```

or

```
string a = ChooseType<string>();
```

Keep in mind that if paramValue cannot be casted as T, then an error will be thrown.